# Azure B2C Signup Flow password validation is missing failure text

Tags: azure, validation, passwords

When signing up a new user, the password field is setup to require a complex password.  While entering the information a warning pops up if the field does not match the security pattern.  If the user ignores that and tries to create the account, the warning about the password disappears and the heading says "One or More Fields are filled out incorrectly. Please check your entries and try again".

Problem is we are getting support calls from new users that can't create accounts because the warning about which specific field causing the error is hidden.  They are left to guess which field is filled out incorrectly. Why does the B2C signup flow hide the fact that the passwords are not strong enough after they continue?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'm running into this as well.  It's not a very good error message for a password not meeting the complexity requirements.

However, it is possible to modify the error message via the "Language Customization" feature.

It's a part of the user flow "Languages" tab.

[image: B2C Language customization]

The docs for language customization are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-user-flow

The feature is also available for custom policies.